# Is it efficient to use Threads like that?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I'm trying to understand Thread logic. As you know, all documents on the web tells about 2 ways of using thread.

1. Extending Thread class
2. Implementing Runnable interface

But I do not understand a point. Why should I use one of them if I am able to create Runnable methods?  Because making a method runnable is the ultimate solution in most cases, I think.

Here is simple example I tried:

```
public class ThreadTest extends JFrame {

    JButton btn1 = new JButton("1asd");
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("2asd");

    ThreadTest() {
        btn1.setLocation(0, 0);
        btn2.setLocation(380, 380);

        add(btn1);
        add(btn2);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 400);
    }

    Runnable sagaCek = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    btn1.setLocation((int) (btn1.getLocation().getX() + 1), 0);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("saga cekiyor");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ThreadTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };

    Runnable yukariCek = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    btn2.setLocation(0, (int) (btn2.getLocation().getY() + 1));
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("yukari cekiyor");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ThreadTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadTest tt = new ThreadTest();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(tt.sagaCek);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(tt.yukariCek);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

If I am able to divide methods of class into Threads, why do I need to make class Runnable and call Thread from class constructor. I would appreciate a lot if I could take further advices on Threads.

Comment: The ultimate solution is not to use `Thread`s at all. Please take a look at [executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you created there are not "`Runnable` methods". `sagaCek` and `yukariCek` are instances of corresponding anonymous classes that implements `Runnable`.

You can check this by calling `sagaCek.getClass()`, and observing `ThreadTest$1.class` as a result. So in fact you are using the 2nd method of creating a thread.

Answer (score 0):

A Runnable with a run method is just a piece of code.

You can execute it directly by calling runnable.run() but doing that, the code is execute in current thread, sequentially.

You can also execute this piece of code into another concurrent thread by creating a thread like new Thread(runnable) and starting the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the discussion is not about "Ultimate solution" but about proper design.

You inherite from `Thread` class when you want to create a costumized thread.
You implement `Runnable` when your object can run in parallel but is not a Thread directly. 
That is it, there is no "better" solution or ultimate one.

A `JFrame` is not a thread nor something that run in parallel. it's a graphical object. Thus (in my opinion), `JFrame` is not suitable not as a costimzed thread an not as a runnable object. it is suited to be  member of a runnable object, if that makes any sense to the scenario given.

PS.
in your example, you **are** implementing `Runnable`, just as anonymous class.

Comment: I mean if I had implemented Runnable with 'implmenets' there was going to be a single run method. So I was going to use it just for one function. And if I had extended Thread class I was goint to create 2 different classes for 'sagaCek' and 'yukariCek'.  But this example lets me create two methods in same class. Am I losing efficency, simplicity or speed of process-program?

Comment: again, it's a design thing. usually a class does only one thing, and it does it good. so it make sense to implement one asynchronous method which is the "main" of the new thread, rather then many.